# Does this seem like discrimination?

Tags: interviewing, discrimination

I have 12+ years experience in call centers, I have started at the bottom and worked my way to the top over about 8 years. I have held every position there is in a call center. When I was on the phones as a sales rep I was consistently a top rep, I know how to sell and my resume shows it.

I live in Maine, in my area there are only so many call centers, so this company is pretty much the only game in town for this type of work. I applied once in June, had an interview which seemed to go great the guy told me the training class was starting in a week and he would call Wednesday with more info. When I get home I already had an email from them saying thanks but no thanks! This made no sense after what he had told me, I asked a friend to find out what he could and he said the guy thought I only wanted management but he would contact me now. Never heard from him..

Now its October, my unemployment is running out and I need a job badly, one of my past co-managers was a manager at this company now so he put in a good word, got me an interview the next day, it was with the same guy. So he told me the same thing again about before but I said no worries. So again the interview goes great he seems interested! So hes interested, i have a recommendation from a manager and a perfect resume for a call center job, I 'm thinking I am in! When I left the interview the guy said he was going to talk to the other manager (my friend) before he made the decision.

Again, when i got home already was an email saying thanks but no thanks! So obviously after our interview he talked to nobody, which I later confirmed with my friend, and immediately sent me the email.

I am disabled, I had a major brain injury in 2006 leaving me with long term memory problems and some short term however this never effected my ability on the phones!

I feel like I am being discriminated against for some reason because I know how call centers hire, they never tell anyone no unless they have a record, I have no record at all.

Do you think this could qualify as discrimination??

Comment: Are you sure they even know that you are disabled?

Comment: How can you be sure it didn't affect your ability?  I wouldn't be surprised if your problem is forgetting things during the interview.

Comment: There's not enough information to know if you are being discriminated against. The only conclusion to draw from this is that you have been granted interviews but not yet hired. Do you have any other feedback from the employer?

Comment: I told them I was disabled because they were asking questions about high school and I cant remember much before I was in the accident, it would have been an awkward silence had I not explained myself!

Comment: I know it hasn't affected my ability on the phones because of the amount of sales I make on the phones.

Comment: I received the emails telling me I was not selected for the job, and both interviews the gentleman has lied to me. I have more than enough ability to do the job, just doesn't feel right...

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is always no.

Comment: *GF Marketing*? What does that mean? Please explain, or if it's a company name, edit it out.

Comment: *So obviously after our interview he talked to nobody* You cannot conclude that.

Comment: What do you mean with *they never tell anyone no unless they have a record*?

Comment: *I told them I was disabled because they were asking questions* That should be in your question. Please [edit]

Comment: You were rejected a mere two times and immediately conclude that you must be being discriminated against? Wow. I'm not sure where to begin. Let's see, the job market is a nightmare right now, especially for unskilled labour (i.e. call centers). You have 8 years experience but are apparently applying for an entry level call center job, which is an automatic non-starter. You do *not* know how all call centers hire (no one does).

Comment: And to top it all off you applied for the same job at the same company in a matter of months (presumably without even acknowledging that fact) so let's be honest, you weren't even rejected twice. You were rejected once and refused to take no for an answer. Finally, even if you were being discriminated against (you weren't), that doesn't help you in any way. VTC.

Comment: Is it at all possible that your brain injury is affecting the hiring process? You said you brought up your brain injury when asked about High School, which seems like a unusual time to bring up the brain injury problem as they usually simply ask if you graduated. Is it at all possible that you might have forgotten something during the interview?

Answer (score 7):

From what you are saying, there is no way that manager could know that you had a brain injury in 2006 unless either you or your friend spilled the beans. Given that your short-term cognitive abilities are not affected, there is no way for that manager to suspect that you have a brain injury. If he doesn't know that you have a brain injury, how could he discriminate against you on the basis of a brain injury that he doesn't know you have?

I suggest you apply to other companies and that you use your friend as reference. Because as long as that manager is in there, you are not getting in.

Comment: This answer is no longer 'valid', because the OP adds a comment response *I told them I was disabled because they were asking questions* 3 hours alter.

Comment: @JanDoggen Aye, but unfortunately the last sentence still holds.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever they are looking for, you aren't it. It happens. There's no need to read more into it than that. Continue interviewing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.K. It makes sense to let potential employers be aware of disabilities at the application stage.

With a lot of larger employers they have a company wide policy to ALWAYS interview disabled applicants that on paper have the technical skills for the role.

Employers also have a legal duty to make reasonable adjustments for your disability both at the interview stage and in the job if you are hired to allow you to work effectively.

Now, in your situation, under US law, It is impossible for us to say for this one particular company why the recruiter was not selecting you.

To support a discrimination allegation there would need to be either a bit of evidence that showed that something based on your disability was a significant aspect of rejecting your application,  or you would need to establish that your rejection was part of a wider consistent pattern of discrimination by this recruiter and/or company.

My advise would be to use your friends to understand via the back channels what were the issues that made you not selected for hiring.

Sometimes these decisions are not based on anything you can control.  I've rejected a candidate that was technically competent, but the role was on my team, and I would have struggled to manage them.

Comment: In some places, companies may be required to hire a certain percentage of disabled people. If you have a disability that doesn't affect your job and doesn't require any costly accommodation, you are the perfect person to hire in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot know. Because you don't know. It's pretty clear by now that the manager *does not want* to employ you. The decision was swift and final. Twice. Applying a third time will probably yield the same result.

There is no indication that you were discriminated against. So where you? Nobody but the hiring manager knows. That's not a very satisfactory answer, but you will need to find another job opportunity.